# get an array from a web service into a pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, nsurlsession, mlab

I currently have a webservice link that has a question and an array of answers. I need my pickerview to load these answers however this is not loading the array at all or any data. The name of the array is called "Answers"

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usernamelabel: UILabel! //sets username label
@IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton! //next button
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel! //item user has selected
@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel! //sets question label
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView! //sets picker view

public var totalQuestions: Int = 0 //sets total question to 0
public var currentQuestion = 0  //sets current question to 0
public var totalCorrect: Int = 0 //sets totalcorrect to 0
var itemSelected: String = "" //item selected
var LabelText = String()
//let Exam = QuestionList() //uses the questions class for instances
//var Questions = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()
@IBOutlet weak var share: UIButton!


//var listQuestions = [[String: AnyObject]]()

var listQuestions = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var titles: [String] = []



var quiz = QuestionList()

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var refHandle: UInt!


override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad() //when the app is loaded
    //authPlayer()

    let url:String = "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/quiz/collections/question?apiKey=NT28RNl6jX3Ys0x5GJZ6mMSRQEcb_6KA"

    let urlRequest = URL(string: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        else{
            do{
                self.listQuestions = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                //self.tableview.reloadData()

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()


    share.isHidden = true

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() //reference
    refHandle = ref.child("Questions").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot)in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        print (dataDict)
    })
     usernamelabel.text = LabelText //username

     pickerview.delegate = self

    itemLabel.text = "" //loads the item label of whats selected
    totalQuestions = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions().count
    itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[currentQuestion] //initially when loaded first item is selected
    itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[1]
    //Question.text = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].quest
    //Question.text = Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][0] //first element in first row of array
    Question.text = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].quest
    //cell.EventImgView.image = event["Image"] as? UIImage

    //Question.text = q["Title"] as? String




}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1 //return one component from the picker
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    //return QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers.count
    //let q = listQuestions[row]
    //return listQuestions[currentQuestion].count[row]
    //return listQuestions.count[row]
    return listQuestions.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{


    //return QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[row]
    let q = listQuestions[row]
    return q["Answers"] as? String

    //cell.EventImgView.image = event["Image"] as? UIImage

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

    itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[row]

}

@IBAction func btnShareClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {

        let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        //fbShare.setInitialText("You Scored on the IT Quiz:" + itemLabel.text!)
        fbShare.setInitialText("You Scored " + itemLabel.text! + " on the IT Quiz")
        self.present(fbShare, animated:true, completion:nil)

    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Account", message: "Please login to Facebook",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

func addGC(_ sender: Any) {


}

/*func authPlayer() {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
        (view, error) in

        if view != nil {
            self.present(view!, animated:true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated)
        }
    }

}

func saveHighScore(score: String) {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated {

    }
}*/





@IBAction func NextAction(_ sender: Any){


    if (QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].isCorrectQuestion(itemSelected: itemSelected)) {
        totalCorrect += 1
        itemLabel.text = String(totalCorrect) + "/" + String(totalQuestions)
    }

    if(currentQuestion < totalQuestions - 1) {
        pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
        itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[1]
        Question.text = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].quest
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1 //moves onto next question and increments


    } else {
        pickerview.isHidden = true
        Question.text = "You have finished"
        Next.isHidden = true
        share.isHidden = false;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The picker view is empty as you need to reload the picker view after you receive the JSON response. So after this line

```
self.listQuestions = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Add in

```
self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
```

------- EDIT ------

The reason you don't see anything is because your JSON parsing is wrong. You JSON returns Answers, Questions & _id back. Your listQuestions is going to be these 3 elements. What you need to do  is extract the array of answers.

As right now, your doing

```
let q = listQuestions[row]
return q["Answers"] as? String
```

q would be an array for element [0], a string for element [1] and a dictionary for element [2]

--- EDIT ----
Ok so as I said, your second problem is that you have not parsed your JSON into the correct format so the title won't show. 
You already declared a titles array so change your code to this

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        else{
            do{
                self.listQuestions = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                for elements in self.listQuestions {
                    for object in elements {
                        if object.key == "Answers" {
                            if let answers = object.value as? [String] {
                                self.titles = answers
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

Then obviously update your picker view delegate methods to

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    return self.titles[row]
}
```

&

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return titles.count
}
```

Comment: This is still not loading the components within the pickerview?

Comment: Well, it will. But your code is wrong. Let me edit my answer to explain

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so how would I get the answers array element within my code? Thanks

Comment: Hold on, I'll have to run this to check

Comment: thanks its working fine however my currentquestion and totalquestion are having issues

Comment: If you have other issues then you need to create another question on SO and tell us what is wrong. As the picker view is displaying answers now you can accept this answer